# Pulse Audio Changing Sample Rate on the Fly

Tags: pulseaudio

I have two audio outputs:

- Headphone out (mobo)
- Displayport audio out (amd gpu)

Headphone output works if `default-sample-rate = 44100` in `.pulse/daemon.conf`, whereas displayport only works if `default-sample-rate = 48000`. It does not seem that having `alternate-sample-rate` set to the alternative value of `default-sample-rate` makes any impact.

My current process for switching audio output is:

- Modify `default-sample-rate` to the desired output sample rate.
- `pulseaudio -k`
- Open `pavucontrol` and change default output.
- Restart programs outputting audio.

The above process works reliably, but is obviously *not great*.

**Is there anyway for pulse to manage this for me?**